# Why do I have a problem when I instantiate the toolbar in the onCreate of my activity?

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, android-toolbar

In my AddCity Activity I got a problem whenever I instantiate the Toolbar in the onCreate method , this Toolbar just displays a title and have an up arrow and I need to  handle the action of the up arrow , when I run the app some error occurs and causes the app to close but when I remove the instantiating of the Toolbar from the onCreate everything goes fine, can anyone explain this to me?

Here is the code of the AddCity class :

```
    public class AddCity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_city);

    Toolbar addCityToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.addCityToolbar);

    addCityToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

And here is the Layout file of

The AddCity Activity :

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <Linearlayouts   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    android:id="@+id/addCityToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="@string/ADD_CITY_TOOLBAR_TITLE" />

<SearchView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutMode="clipBounds"
    android:outlineProvider="paddedBounds"
    android:queryHint="@android:string/search_go" />
```

Comment: Can you share the error message that appears on the console?

Comment: You say there is "*some error*". **What** error do you get?

Comment: It might be because of the themes. I suggest you to check that.

Comment: Make sure you are importing `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` and not `android.support.app.AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: The problem was because I imported android.widget.Toolbar instead of androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar, thanks to all of you who have tried to help :)